# Let, $G$ be a subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb{C})$. Prove that, $\exists$ an inner product on $\Bbb{C}^n$ such that $G\subset U_n$

Tags: group-theory, inner-products, group-actions, unitary-matrices

Here, $U_n$ denotes the set of unitary matrices in $GL_n(\Bbb{C})$ i.e. $U_n=\{A\in GL_n(\Bbb{C})|AA^*=A^*A=I\}$
We have to find an inner product $\langle,\rangle$ on $\Bbb{C}^n$ .
I have to prove that $G\subset U_n$ i.e. $\forall A\in G$ we must have $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ (This is an equivalent definition of the unitary matrix).
There is a hint provided in the book-
We can define a group action $G\times \Bbb{C}^n\to\Bbb{C}^n$ by $(A,v)\mapsto Av$
This group action can help you to get this $\langle,\rangle$.
But I don't have any idea how to proceed from here. Can anyone help me solve the problem? Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: Is G supposed to be finite?

Comment: So can $G$ be all of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: As per the question as $G$ has to be included in $U_n$, G must be proper, I think so.

Comment: @Nate It's not mentioned that G is finite. But if you thik as a subcase or to simplify you can prove it assuming G to be finite

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for delimiters/inner products, rather than `<` and `>`. The spacing is wrong for the latter. Compare $\langle x,y\rangle$ with $<x,y>$.

Comment: The hint is not a hint at all. The classic way to do this is "Weyl's unitary trick" aka the "averaging trick." But this really only works for closed, compact subgroups though. The statement is false for general groups $G$. Hence the reason for Nate and Hagen's comments, which you didn't really respond well to. Clearly if $G$ is all of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ it has too big of a dimension to be contained in the unitary group no matter what the inner product is, which makes it weird when you say "I think so" in response to "$G$ can be all of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$."

Comment: Where are you getting the problem from? Are you missing some context that says what $G$ can be?

Comment: I thik $G$ have to be finite. If we choose $G$ to be the subgroup generated by $2I$ (where $I$ denotes the identity matrix) in $GL_n(\Bbb{C})$ and if there is an inner product such that $G\subset U_n$ then $2I$ is an unitary matrix with respect to the new inner product. So $\langle 2I(x),2I(y)\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle\implies 4\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle\implies \langle x,y\rangle=0$, for all $x,y$. This is contradiction.

Comment: For finite $G$ I have constructed an inner product. Let, $(,)$ denotes the usual inner product on $\Bbb{C}^n$. Then I define $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{A\in G} (Ax,Ay)$. If $G$ is infinite then this sum may not converge for all $x,y\in \Bbb{C}^n$. I hope this inner product will do the job (i.e. $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$)when $G$ is finite.